# Limit a foreign key constraint by condition on parent table column?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

Note: After posting I added additional "requirements" to the question, they are in *italics*.

How could one limit a foreign key constraint so, that it enforces references to rows by the key value an one additional condition (based on a column value in the parent table *and one in the child table*)?

For example in the parent *and child* table we have an column named *expired*. If it has the value "yes" (I use the values '0' and '1' in the example below) *in the parent table*, then no children should reference that row *except if the child row also has expired='1'*.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33931/1

Basically, if *expired* is set to '1' in either table, those rows should be "ignored" as far as FK references are concerned.

(I'm looking for a solution for Oracle, but general ideas are welcome too)

MT0, your answer is great for the original question, thanks.

Comment: can you show an example?

Answer (score 1):

Use a virtual column with a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE PARENTS (
  id       INT PRIMARY KEY,
  valid    INT CHECK ( valid IN (0,1) ),
  valid_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( CASE valid WHEN 1 THEN id END )
               UNIQUE
);


CREATE TABLE Children (
  id        INT PRIMARY KEY,
  parent_id INT REFERENCES Parents ( valid_id )
);
```

If you do:

```
INSERT INTO parents ( id, valid ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
INSERT INTO parents ( id, valid ) VALUES ( 2, 0 );

INSERT INTO Children ( id, parent_id ) VALUES ( 1, 1 );
```

The inserts work but this one:

```
INSERT INTO Children ( id, parent_id ) VALUES ( 2, 2 );
```

Results in:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TEST.SYS_C009124) violated - parent key not found
```